# Process stuck when using splinter browser visiting some website

Tags: python, web-scraping, timeout, splinter

Good day. I am new to web scraping automation and just start to do some tests on package splinter.
My working env as below:

1. OS : Ubuntu20.04 (on Windows10, without gui)
2. IDE : Vscode
3. Language : Python
4. Package : splinter 0.14.0

I was following some tutorial and execute code as below which work perfectly :

```
from splinter import Browser

executable_path = {"executable_path" : r'/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'}
browser = Browser(driver_name = 'chrome', **executable_path, headless =True)
browser.visit('https://www.google.com')
print(browser.title)
# return Google
browser.quit()
```

However, when I tried with some other websites like https://tw.yahoo.com/?p=us then system stuck for
a while and return error message as below:

```
File "/home/stevetsaoch/Tradebot/main.py", line 23, in <module>
browser.visit('https://tw.yahoo.com/?p=us')
File "/home/stevetsaoch/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/__init__.py", line 287, in visit
self.driver.get(url)
File "/home/stevetsaoch/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
File "/home/stevetsaoch/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/home/stevetsaoch/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 299.850
(Session info: headless chrome=87.0.4280.141)
```

For my understanding, the message above suggests that my chrome was unable to find https://tw.yahoo.com/?p=us and after searching for a default period it returns a timeout error. By the way, I had checked https://tw.yahoo.com/?p=us with my chrome on windows at the same time, and it responses in a very short time.
Is there any suggestion for this situation? Any suggestion or comment is appreciated.

Comment: By the way, when I using python shell on **Windows 10** and run the same code,  visiting https://tw.yahoo.com/?p=us, the code works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I do some research and got an answer.
I forgot to set up Xvfb lib. After I ran codes in my bash as below:

```
Xvfb :99 -ac
export DISPLAY=:99
```

The problem was solved!